# How to pass trustStore info to kafka client configuration

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, truststore

I'm trying to collect data stream from nasdaq in NodeJS the same way they are doing it on this repository with Java https://github.com/Nasdaq/CloudDataService.

The problem I'm facing is that I can't find any way to pass the trust :

```
const kafka = new Kafka({
  clientId: 'client-id',
  brokers: ['borker:9094'],
  // authenticationTimeout: 1000,
  // reauthenticationThreshold: 10000,
  ssl: true,
  sslOptions: {
    trustStore: "ncdsTrustStore.p12",
    trustStorePassword:"pass_word",
    trustStoreType:"PKCS12"
  },
  logLevel: logLevel.ERROR,
  sasl: {
    mechanism: 'oauthbearer',
    oauthBearerProvider: async () => {
      const token = "TOKEN"
      console.log(token)
      return {
        value: token
      }
    }
  },
})
```

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: I wonder also whether you found a solution?